# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.restlet.service.TunnelService command line

Tags: java, jar, classnotfoundexception, restlet

I am using the Restlet framework.

I am trying to run my project from a jar file created using Eclipse, by doing: **Export->Runnable JAR File**, and selecting the option Package required libraries into generated jar.

However, when I try to execute the jar file in the command line, by typing:

```
java -Djava.security.policy=Client.Policy -jar identiscopeRunnable.jar
```

I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/restlet/service/TunnelService
at rest.IdentiscopeServer.main(IdentiscopeServer.java:24)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.restlet.service.TunnelService
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 6 more
```

I have added all the jar files downloaded from the Restlet Framework to my project, so I presume it is not a problem with them. Does anyone have any clue about this?

Just in case anyone asks, the line 24 of `IdentiscopeServer.java` is:

```
IdentiscopeServerApplication identiscopeServerApp = new IdentiscopeServerApplication();
```

The class `IdentiscopeServerApplication` basically does this:

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());

    //attaches the /tweet path to the TweetRest class
    router.attach("/collectionPublic", CollectionPublicREST.class);
    router.attach("/collectionPrivate", CollectionPrivateREST.class);
    router.attach("/analysis", AnalysisREST.class);
    return router;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the jars to your eclipse project will not add the jars to your command line classpath.

```
java -cp <add your jars here separated by ';'(win) or ':'(linux) > -Djava.security.policy=Client.Policy -jar identiscopeRunnable.jar
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try that. Is there a way to include all the jars faster? Cause there are a lot of them

Comment: If I remember correctly, using Netbeans you just need to edit some .xml file and add the jars that you want to export along with the project jar, and then Build does the rest. Isn't there anything similar on Eclipse?

Comment: I tried adding the org.restlet.jar like you said and I got the same error.